# How to optimize SELECT COUNT with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: performance, mariadb, join, count

I have a MariaDB 10.5.10 database, with a table `activity` made of 150,000 rows. it holds:

- an `id` field (integer, primary key)
- a `tenant`. There are about 85,000 rows with tenant = 12
- an `activity_type` (integer, acting as a key to another table `activity_type`)

Another table, `activity_type`, has 6 rows, with an `id` (primary key, integer)

This query, which is generated from an ORB (and which I can virtually not modify) requires about 4-5 seconds to execute, and I would like to make it run faster:

```
select count(activity.id) from activity
   left join activity_type on activity.type = activity_type.id
where tenant = 12 ;
```

When I remove the `left join` row, it runs much faster, about 0.7 seconds.

Using `explain`, I can see that without `left join`, the `extra` column mentions `using index`(actually, the index on the `tenant` column):

```
explain select SQL_NO_CACHE count(activity.id) from activity
where tenant = 12;
```

[image]

But with `left join` the `extra` column is empty:

```
explain select SQL_NO_CACHE count(activity.id) from activity
  left join activity_type on activity.type = activity_type.id
where tenant = 12;
```

[image]

And with `left join` but NO `where` clause, it also shows `Using index`:

```
explain select SQL_NO_CACHE count(activity.id) from activity
  left join activity_type on activity.type = activity_type.id;
```

[image]

Could you please help me improving the performance when both the `LEFT JOIN` and the `WHERE` statements are present?

Please note that:

- the `LEFT JOIN` does not add any rows to the results, because there is only one `activity_type` row per activity (I have also tried to add a `UNIQUE` index on the `activity_type.id`, but it does not change anything on performance)
- however I need the `LEFT JOIN` statement, because in some cases, the users might want to add more criteria (in the `where` clause) related to the fields in the `activity_type` table.

Many thanks!

Comment: When you remove the left join, does it give you the correct answer?  If not, why not?

Comment: Which is it?  `activity_type` or `activity.type` -- You have inconsistencies.

Comment: activity.type refers to the ID in the activity_type table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following index to the `activity` table

```
alter table activity add index tp_ten(type,tenant);
```

See [Compound (Composite) Indexes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compound-composite-indexes/)

Comment: Many thanks! Actually this one didn't work exactly, but (tenant,type) did. Thanks again! (Indeed it's still a bit mysterious to me how such an index can be used by both a left join and a where, but the result is there ;) )

Comment: How can either index work???  An INDEX cannot reference columns in different tables!

Answer (score 0):

> I need the LEFT JOIN statement, because in some cases, the users might want to add more criteria (in the where clause) related to the fields in the activity_type table.

No you don't.  Construct the desired query based on the criteria the user give you.  It appears that `AND activity_type = '...'` is the only case where the `LEFT JOIN` clause is needed.

Other tips:

- Say `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(x)` unless you need to check for `x IS NOT NULL`.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so that we know exactly what indexes, datatypes, etc, are in the tables.
- MariaDB (but not MySQL) is smart enough to get rid of any `LEFT JOIN` that is not really needed.

The EXPLAINs:

1. In InnoDB, the PK is implicitly tacked onto any secondary index.  This means it is "Using index" `(tenent, id)`
2. The empty "Extra" is probably due to thinking it needs `type`.
3. The `PRIMARY KEY(id)` 'clustered' as an "index" for the data.  So, "Using index" *in this case* means "table scan".

Confused?  I don't blame you.

I would use a short string for "types" and include it as a column in `activity`.  That would eliminate the `JOIN` (unless there is something else of interest in the 'types' table).  But then, you might need `INDEX(tenant, type)`, especially for the simplified version of the original query.